# Counting occurrences of words per each item in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list: ['cat dog', 'cat cat', 'dog', 'cat cat cat']

I want the count for 'cat' to be 3 (unique per item in the list, not 6).

I'm currently using:

```
counts = [cat dog, cat cat, dog, cat cat cat]
for sentence in sequence_of_sentences:
    counts.update(word for word in sentence.split())
```

Updated: Should be 3 instances of cat :)

Comment: I can't see where this `4` comes from

Comment: should this be 3 and not 4?

Comment: Without a better explanation this problem is insoluble.

Comment: Sorry. Epic fail. Should have been 3, not 4.

Comment: it does. @istruble had the right solution for me, since I didn't want it specific to a term, but to generate all counts. We're good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).  `Counter` is very handy for creating tallies (aka. counting) and `set` is great for removing duplicates from a sequence.

```
from collections import Counter

phrases = ['cat dog', 'cat cat', 'dog', 'cat cat cat']    
all_counts = Counter()
occurrence_counts = Counter()

for phrase in phrases:
    words = phrase.split()
    distinct_words = set(words)
    all_counts.update(words)
    occurrence_counts.update(distinct_words)

all_counts['cat']        # 6
occurrence_counts['cat'] # 3
```

[`update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) updates the tallies based on what you pass it.

Play around with `set` a bit by running python from from command line and you should get an idea for what is going on above:

```
$ python
>>> animals = [ 'bird', 'bird', 'cat' ]
>>> set(animals)
set(['bird', 'cat'])
>>> list(set(animals))
['bird', 'cat']
```

Comment: might you be able to explain (for a beginner like me) how allcounts.update(words) and occurrencecounts.update(set(words)) works?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand how you get `4`. Your example list

```
>>>l=['cat dog', 'cat cat', 'dog', 'cat cat cat']
```

has `3` unique `'cat'`'s. First, Second and Last element. In case you want that, use

```
>>>sum(1 for i in l if 'cat' in i)
```

or as @holden excellently suggests (it would have never occurred to me)

```
>>>sum(('cat' in i) for i in l)
```

which reads excellently.

Comment: Since Booleans also have numerical values (False is 0 and True is 1) your last could be rewritten `sum(('cat' in i) for i in l). As we don't understand the question yet your answer might have better been made as a comment. I can't figure out why 4 either!

Comment: @holdenweb I think it was a typo. Either three or there should be another `,` in there somewhere. Hard to say, I had to edit in the single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, well I'm going to reserve my psychic powers for determining lottery winners.

Comment: OP has mysteriously disappeared as well. I am only using my psychic powers for good. *OR* we could do `def count(l):return 4 #chosen by OP`